# Have I inadvertely diethyl ether peroxides?

Tags: safety

About 1 week ago, I used diethyl ether to wash some solid products.

I dumped it in my temporary waste container, which also contains water and some other solvents like DCM.

I returned today, and discovered that my waste container is full of yellow to brown crystals, and possibly some oil of similar color.

Needless to say I didnt stick around for long to investigate or even touch anything, as I realized that I might have turned my fume hood into a minefield (ether peroxides are friction explosive).

I wilk of course E&HS at my faculty, but it's saturday so no one is around.

Is it plausible that I've made dangerous peroxides? Has anyone else done the very stupid thing which is to store diethyl ether alongside with water in an open container for 1 week?

Comment: Diethyl ether left in an open container will be completely gone in a matter of hours. Peroxides are scary, but I wouldn't expect them here.

Comment: Additional comment.  Try not to contaminate organic solvents waste with water based one as it can pose severe corrosion problems at a big and  further stages of the disposal process. Moreover the treatment of halogenated waste is more expensive and is not economic to add too much not alogenated mass to it.

Comment: @Alchimista It depends on the waste solvent removal policies of the institute. When I did my bachelor’s, we separated organic, halogen-organic and aquaeous. When I arrived at my master’s, halogen-organic and organic were no longer separated because people were too stupid to do that (that was the reason they gave!). When I did my PhD at a different institute, everything was poured into a single container. Now as a postdoc on the other side of the planet, all three are separated again.

Comment: It's only halogen containing org. solvents and non-halogen containing org. solvents here. No rules about getting water in either one of them, although you're advised to use your head and not do things like pouring saline water into the halogen container (dissolved NaCl is technically 'halogen containing'...)